# How to Restrict two users of ubuntu to see other's data

Tags: permissions, users

I have installed ubuntu with two folders i.e. / and /home with swap area.
I have made two users in /home.
But User1 can check the data of User2 and hence vice-versa.
I wish to restrict one user to see other's data.
Please suggest me how to do so.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. do NOT follow ggalaxy's comment. 2. 11.10 is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

get a root-shell:

```
sudo -i
```

go to the home directory

```
cd /home
```

change permission of the folder you want by:

```
chmod 750 [USER_FOLDER_NAME]
```

this will give read/write/exec to owner read/exec for group and no permission for other users

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answer is completely correct, note that this is a call each user can do. When you log in you can see the permissions on your home directory:

```
$ ls -ld $HOME
rwxr-xr-x 111 rmano rmano 12288 Feb 10 14:13 .
```

`rwx` means that the owner can read, write and cross(1) the directory. The members of group `rmano` can just read and cross. The last triple specify what to do with "others" users. So if you do (as user):

```
chmod o-rwx $HOME
```

you will restrict the access to all "other" users. (Don't do that with the group, it's not needed. In a normal installation you are the only member of your group). Now:

```
$ ls -ld $HOME
rwxr-x--- 111 rmano rmano 12288 Feb 10 14:13 .
```

This is the same effect of the other answer; but keep clear that even if you change permissions with the root account, the user can still decide to change the permission back to make his/her files visible.

(1) `x` means execute for files, "cross"for directories.